# Why does this produce an infinite loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to assign a field in an ActiveRecord model (pos), to a value 1+ the highest value so far. The following, in either version, produces an infinite loop. I can't figure out why. Can you see it?

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :text, :pos, :data_type, :active
  has_many :values
  belongs_to :program

  after_initialize :assign_pos

  def row_label
    text
  end

  def self.highest_pos
    self.order("pos DESC").first
  end

  def assign_pos
    puts "********* #{Question.highest_pos + 1}" # option 1
    self.pos = Question.highest_pos + 1 # option 2
  end

end
```

Comment: That's not the way to do it. Let the database increment the value. Only drawback is that you won't know the new value in advance until the record is saved.

Comment: Also it's not a straight increment as the user in between might have changed the pos value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `assign_pos` method is actually initializing `self.pos`, so because of the `after_initialize` condition, `assign_pos` gets called again, and initializes `self.pos`...

Answer (score 1):

"self.order..." is actually selecting the object from the database, and calling initialize.  After initialize it is calling assign_pos, which calls highest_pos, which starts everything all over again.